# C# Disable Certificate Warning

Tags: c#, browser, certificate, web

With the windows forms web browser, I am visiting a page that has an expired certificate. 
When I proceed to click on it, it does not let me pass unless I am using the actual internet explorer.
How can I disable this warning either through code or just through the internet options?

I have already unchecked 'warn about certificate address mismatch' but it does not solve the issue.